# Pass the Content of Multiple .txt file to while/read/do at One Go

Tags: regex, bash, while-loop

I am trying to pass multiple .txt files into a while/read/do loop.

The files have the pattern below:

```
File_1st.txt
File_2nd.txt
File_3rd.txt
```

I am trying to use a regex:

```
while read i
do
 $COMMAND $i
done < File*.txt
```

However this gives me the *ambiguous redirect* 
How can I do this? How can I read each file line by line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a useful use of `cat`:

```
cat File*.txt | while read i
do
 $COMMAND "$i"
done
```

Or, if you need to avoid the subshell for the while loop:

```
while read i
do
 $COMMAND "$i"
done < <(cat File*.txt)
```

Comment: thanks for that. I was looking at the second method but I was missing a '<'.